# R unpivot columns with ranked combination

Tags: r, reshape, data-manipulation

I have the following data frame whose `dput` sample is:

```
MyData <- structure(list(Tag = c("Tag1", "Tag1","Tag1", "Tag1","Tag1", "Tag1","Tag1", "Tag2","Tag2", "Tag2"), id = c(15227L, 16368L, 15121L, 15122L,15123L, 15124L, 15125L, 15391L, 15392L, 15393L), dimension_r = c(10,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,5L, 6L, 7L, 62L, 63L, 64L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like this:

```
Tag     ID      Rank
Tag1    15227   10
Tag1    16368   2
Tag1    15121   3
Tag1    15122   4
Tag1    15123   5
Tag1    15124   6
Tag1    15125   7
Tag2    15391   6
Tag2    15392   7
Tag2    15393   8
```

and I want to reformat it to be like below:

```
Tag     lower greater
Tag1    16368 15121     
Tag1    15121 15122     
Tag1    15122 15123 
Tag1    15123 15124
Tag1    15124 15125
Tag1    15125 15227 
Tag2    15391 15392
Tag2    15392 15393
```

I'm guessing I need to use dcast for this but not sure how to program it in order to take the rank and unpivot the frame in that way.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain what I need to make in order to clarify my question. I've edited my post. Is it now clear?

Comment: Yes, very good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using simply `dplyr`, you can do as following:

1.`Arrange()` by Tag and dimension_r.

2.`lag()` a column and filter out NA.

3.`rename()` the column id to the name wanted.

4.`select()` the columns as wanted.

```
library(dplyr)
MyData %>% group_by(Tag)%>%arrange(Tag,dimension_r) %>% 
      mutate(lower = lag(id))%>% 
      filter(!is.na(lower))%>%
      rename(greater = id) %>%
      select(Tag, lower, greater)
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups:   Tag [2]
# Tag   lower greater
# <chr> <int>   <int>
# 1 Tag1  16368   15121
# 2 Tag1  15121   15122
# 3 Tag1  15122   15123
# 4 Tag1  15123   15124
# 5 Tag1  15124   15125
# 6 Tag1  15125   15227
# 7 Tag2  15391   15392
# 8 Tag2  15392   15393
```

Comment: Thank you so much Carles. Saved me a ton of work!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

a data.table approach

1 convert data to data.table, and summarise by Tag by id (creating lower)
 2 use `data.table::shift` to get the next valu by Tag-group
 3 use `na.omit` to throw away incomplete rows.

```
library(data.table)
na.omit( setDT(MyData)[, .(lower = id ), by = .(Tag)][, greater := shift(lower, type = "lead"), by = .(Tag)][] )

   Tag lower greater
1: Tag1 15227   16368
2: Tag1 16368   15121
3: Tag1 15121   15122
4: Tag1 15122   15123
5: Tag1 15123   15124
6: Tag1 15124   15125
7: Tag2 15391   15392
8: Tag2 15392   15393
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, one approach could be to first `order` the data based on `Tag` and `dimension_r`. We split the `newdata` based on `Tag` and create `lower` and `greater` column by neglecting last and first observation respectively.

```
newdata <- MyData[with(MyData, order(Tag, dimension_r)), ]
output <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(newdata, newdata$Tag), function(x) 
        data.frame(Tag = x$Tag[1L], lower = x$id[-nrow(x)], greater = x$id[-1])))
rownames(output) <- NULL

output
#   Tag lower greater
#1 Tag1 16368   15121
#2 Tag1 15121   15122
#3 Tag1 15122   15123
#4 Tag1 15123   15124
#5 Tag1 15124   15125
#6 Tag1 15125   15227
#7 Tag2 15391   15392
#8 Tag2 15392   15393
```

---

We can implement the same logic using `dplyr` and `purrr::map_df`

```
library(dplyr)
MyData %>%
  arrange(Tag, dimension_r) %>%
  group_split(Tag) %>%
  purrr::map_df(~data.frame(Tag = first(.$Tag), 
                lower = .$id[-nrow(.)], greater = .$id[-1]))
```